# Python, массивы

Tags: python, матрицы

Столкнулся с такой задачей:
Допустим есть матрица 3 на 3:

```
[[0,2,1],
[2,0,20],
[1,20,0]]
```

Элементы матрицы — это длины ребер графа
(получается координаты элементов матрицы — это две вершины между которыми проведено ребро данного размера).

Например: элемент расположенный в матрице с координатами (0,1) это 2 
это наше ребро графа, проведенное с вершины(0) в вершину(1) и его длина = 2

Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Так вот мне нужно сделать двумерный массив такого вида: `[[x, y, z], [x, y, z]]`, где "x" и "y" - это координаты элемента "z" в матрице`

Я новичок в этом деле, может эта задача и не сложная, но решить не могу((
(Заранее спасибо за любую информацию)

Comment: `Надеюсь понятно объяснил`  нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [64]: m = [[0,2,1], [2,0,20], [1,20,0]]

In [65]: res = []
    ...: for r in range(len(m)):
    ...:     for c in range(len(m[0])):
    ...:         if c <= r:
    ...:             continue
    ...:         res.append([r, c, m[r][c]])
    ...:

In [66]: res
Out[66]: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 20]]
```

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Все, я допер как это сделать)

```
arr = [[0, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 20],
       [1, 20, 0]]

def coord(arr):
   res = []

   for i in range(len(arr)):
          for j in range(len(arr)):
                 if (arr[i][j] != 0):
                        res.append([i, j, arr[i][j]])

   return res

print(coord(arr))
```